# Can not pass data to laravel controller from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, controller

I stuck in this problem for two days.I don't get any one expert with ajax laravel . I am failing to send data to controller file from ajax . If any one please help me . I will be greatful .

Here is Route

```
Route::get('/',"PostController@index");
Route::post('addpost','PostController@addpost');
```

Here is the form

```
<form>
                {{csrf_field()}}
                    <label for = "title">Title</label>
                    <input type = "text" name = "title"><br>
                    <label for = "body">Body</label>
                    <textarea row= "6" name = "body"></textarea><br>
                    <button class = "btn btn-info" name = "submit" id= "add" type = "submit" value = "submit">Add</button>
         </form>
```

Here the  jquery code.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#add_new_post").hide();
            $("#newpost").click(function(){
                $("#add_new_post").show();
                $(this).hide();
            });
            $("form").on('#submit', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : "{{url('/addpost')}}",
                    data :{
                        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                        'title': $('input[name = title]').val(),
                        'body' : $('input[name = body]').val(),
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                    alert("Test Completed")
              window.location.href = "{{('/home')}}";
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the controller code 
DB is not getting data.

```
    public function addpost(Request $request){
    $data=array();
    $data['title'] = $request->title;
    $data['body'] = $request->body;
    Post::insert(array('title'=>$data['title'],'body'=>$data['body']));

}
```

Comment: `on('submit',` or `on('#submit'`? it should be `on('submit',`

Comment: is there any error that you're getting ?

Comment: You missed : $post->save(); at the end of controller

Answer (score 0):

Updated script

`on('submit',` or `on('#submit'`? it should be `on('submit',`

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#add_new_post").hide();
            $("#newpost").click(function(){
                $("#add_new_post").show();
                $(this).hide();
            });
            $(document).on('click', '#add', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : "{{url('/addpost')}}",
                    data :{
                        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                        'title': $('input[name = title]').val(),
                        'body' : $('input[name = body]').val(),
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                    alert("Test Completed")
              window.location.href = "{{('/home')}}";
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller

```
public function addpost(Request $request){ 
        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->save();
}
```

Comment: You are right but db is not getting data . I have a new modification in controller.`public function addpost(Request $request){
        $data=array();
        $data['title'] = $request->title;
        $data['body'] = $request->body;
        Post::insert(array('title'=>$data['title'],'body'=>$data['body']));
        
    }`

Comment: try this `public function addpost(Request $request){ 
   $post = new Post();
   $post->title = $request->title;
   $post->body = $request->body;
   $post->save();
 }`

Comment: do you have `Post` model?

Comment: I have updated my javascript code. Please check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is wrong:

```
$("form").on('#submit', function(event){});
```

Use :

```
$("form").on('submit', function(event){});
```

or
`$(document).on('click',"#app",function(e){e.preventDefault();//prevent submit` event});
or use

```
<button type="button"> & $(document).on('click',"#app",function(){});
```

Also add : `$post->save();` end of the controller

Answer (score 0):

please use $("form").on('submit', function(event){});
instead of $("form").on('#submit', function(event){});